# How do I programmatically add logging filters?

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to add the rule in my NLog. The rule is:

```
 <rules>
<logger name="*" writeTo="file">
    <filters>
        <when condition="length(message) > 100" action="Ignore" />
        <when condition="equals('${logger}','MyApps.SomeClass')" action="Ignore" />
        <when condition="(level >= LogLevel.Debug and contains(message,'PleaseDontLogThis')) or level==LogLevel.Warn" action="Ignore" />
        <when condition="not starts-with('${message}','PleaseLogThis')" action="Ignore" />
    </filters>
</logger>
```

Now I want to implement it in C# code. I haven't found the sample code online.

Comment: Down vote is okay. Please give me a reason. It is not easy to do it in C# as NLOG odesn't provide the document for adding filter in C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would take a look a look at the [Configuration API](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API) documentation for NLog.  While it doesn't specifically reference filters, it seems like the way to accomplish this programmatically is by using `LoggingRules` to control how log messages are processed.

**Edit**

Like I said, the Configuration API is the way to achieve this.  This example will replicate the following config programmatically:

**Config**

```
<targets>            
    <target name="console" type="Console" />
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console">
        <filters>
            <when condition="not starts-with('${message})', 'PleaseLogThis')" action="Ignore" />
        </filters>
    </logger>
</rules>
```

**Code**

```
// Create the filter
var filter = new ConditionBasedFilter();            
filter.Condition = "not starts-with('${message}','PleaseLogThis')";
filter.Action = FilterResult.Ignore;

// Create the rule to apply the filter to
var consoleTarget = new ColoredConsoleTarget();
var rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget);
rule.Filters.Add(filter);

// Create the config to apply the rule to
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

// Update the log manager with the programmatic config
LogManager.Configuration = config;

// Test Your Logging
var log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

log.Debug("Test");
log.Debug("Filter");
log.Debug("PleaseLogThis");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It doesn't have a filter but I want it. The link is helpless.

Comment: It's not THAT helpless, I was able to use it to figure out a working example  pretty easily.  See my edit.

Comment: Why was my answer unchecked?

Comment: I got an exception at `filter.Action = FilterResult.Log;`. My code likes `filter.Condition = "(level <= " +LogLevel.Fatal +")";
            try
            {
                filter.Action = FilterResult.Log;
            }`

Comment: @love you are making it very difficult to help you.  My answer correctly demonstrates how to add filters programmatically.  If you are getting an exception in your usage then it's probably that you're doing it wrong.  Without seeing what you're doing now I have no way of helping you.  You should consider editing your question with an update with your code and explaining how it is causing an exception.

Comment: Okay, sorry about it. My bad.